error: subprocess-exited-with-error - PySQL
Trying to install MSQL using the pip install PySQL command but getting the following error:
C. Administrator: Command Prompt
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4598] (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install PySQL Collecting PySQL
Using cached pysql-0.16.tar.gz (127 kB) Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
* Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[22 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module> main() File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook (**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel return hook(config_settings)
ΑΛΛΑ
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-snahbmx_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel return self._get_build_requires (config_settings, requirements=[])
ΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑΛΑ
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-snahbmx_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-snahbmx_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script_setup_script)
File "C:\Users\bhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-snahbmx_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup exec(code, locals())
File "<string>", line 31
except Exception, e:
^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried updating the setup.py but nothing changed

The issue would appear to be the expression except Exception, e: which is not valid in Python v 3. And the PySql documentation at pysql 0.16 indicates that it is only available for Python versions 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7, and the last update was 10 years ago.

I have removed the  tag since this isn't related to the SQL language. Instead add a tag for the dbms product you're trying to install. (Perhaps ?)
